# Css working half way

Tags: html, css

Here is my html code :

```
<div class="ObjectList" id="ObjectList">
    <p class="ObjectListTitle" id="Element">TEST</p>
</div>
```

CSS is working fine for class ObjectList but **dosen't work for ObjectListTitle**.

This is my css file

```
#ObjectList{
background-color:red;
height:100%;
width:25%;
}

#ObjectListTitle{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your element doesn't have the ID `ObjectListTitle`, it has the *class* `ObjectListTitle`. You're using an ID selector (`#`) and should be using class selector (`.`)

```
.ObjectListTitle{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dsa22/)

Comment: Thank you for the link to http://jsfiddle.net very usefull...

Answer (score 0):

try this:
You make css in id and apply html source cod to class so,

```
<div class="ObjectList" id="ObjectList">
    <p class="ObjectListTitle" id="Element">TEST</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In css you need to know how different groups of stuff is styled.

Tag `<div></div>`
Styling a tag means that you will style all elements with that tag, in this case all div's.

```
div{background:black;}
```

Class `<div class="foo" id="bar"></div>`
Styling a class means that the css rule is applied to all tags with that class. Meaning that the rule applies to the page as many times as you use the class

```
.foo{background:black;}
```

ID `<div class="foo" id="bar"></div>`
Styling an id is like a class but the id must be unique on a page. Meaning that the rule only applies a maximum of once per page

```
#bar{background:black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code.

HTML

```
<div class="ObjectList" id="ObjectList">
    <p class="ObjectListTitle" id="Element">TEST</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#ObjectList{
background:red;
height:100%;
width:25%;
    padding:10px;
}

.ObjectListTitle{
background:#ff9900;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
}
```